# How can I calculate a percentage of one column by a specific variable?

Tags: r, data-science

I ultimately want to plot the % of total reefs surveyed that are covered with algae by ocean_basin.

DF

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
       group_by(ocean_basin) %>%
       summarise(Prop = 100 *
         sum(algae_area_km, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(reef_area_km, na.rm = TRUE), 
              .groups = 'drop')
```